# Keep variable constant during recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to subtract the average of the list from each instance of the list. But the average changes with each recursion. How to make it so that the average stays static? Here's what I tried:

```
ave' :: (Fractional a, Real b) => [b] -> a
ave' xs = realToFrac (sum' xs) / (fromIntegral $ length xs)

std_series :: (Floating a, Real a) => [a] -> [a]
std_series [] = []
std_series (x:xs) = x - ave' (x:xs) : std_series xs
```

Comment: Well, you'll simply have to pass along the original list!

Comment: I am new to Haskell. Could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: You want to subtract the average of the *original list* from each value in the original list? If so, all you need is `map (subtract $ average xs) xs`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: Why not make an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real code I would go with something like `map (subtract (ave' xs)) xs` as @SwiftsNamesake answered, or `[x - m | let m = ave' xs, x <- xs]` using list comprehensions.

However, if you want to write this out by hand to understand it better, then the approach would be to calculate the average once, then call a helper function that does the recursion. For example:

```
std_series xs = go xs
  where
    m = ave' xs
    go [] = []
    go (y:ys) = y - m : go ys
```

This is also related to a useful technique called the *worker–wrapper transform*, where you have an outer “wrapper” function which sets up a closure containing some fixed parameters, and an inner “worker” function that handles the recursion. For instance, since this is basically `map` but manually inlined, you can look at doing the same transformation for an implementation of `map`:

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Here, we pass `f` to each recursive call of `map`, but we don’t need to do that because it’s fixed, so we can add a helper function that only operates on the list, keeping `f` in its closure:

```
map f = go
  where
    go [] = []
    go (x:xs) = f x : go xs
```

If you want to write type signatures for these local functions, sometimes you’ll need to enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension:

```
std_series :: forall a. (Fractional a) => [a] -> [a]
std_series xs = go xs
  where

    m :: a
    m = ave' xs

    go :: [a] -> [a]
    go [] = []
    go (y:ys) = y - m : go ys
```

Here, `forall a.` defines the scope of `a` so that you can use it in the signatures of `m` and `go`. If you omitted it, Haskell would treat the `a` in the inner type signatures as *different* type variables than the outer `a` (which happens to have the same name), so it would give you an error like:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for std_series ∷ Fractional a ⇒ [a] → [a]
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for m ∷ a1
```

Comment: I liked your detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to subtract the average of the original list from each value in the original list? If so, all you need is `map (subtract $ average xs) xs`.

Comment: Are even more dry way of doing it : `subtract . average >>= map`.  To be used only if you understand `Monad ((->) r)`

Comment: Shorter, but hardly any clearer. This isn't code golf.

Comment: I do not claim that this is better, reason why I haven't put it as a proper answer. This is an alternative if you do not like to name arguments.

Comment: @mathk Fair enough.

Comment: @mathk: For this pattern of `\ x -> f (g x) x` in point-free code, I tend to prefer `<*>`, e.g., `ffor <*> subtract . average` (“for each element, subtract the average”) where `ffor = flip fmap`. Here it’s not really worthwhile, though.